# Can't get BBP formula to work in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, math, pi

I've been trying to make a little program that can compute the n-th digit of pi.

After a few searches I've found that the most common formula is the BBP formula, wich is n-th digit = 16^-n[4/(8n + 1)-2/(8n + 4)-1/(8n + 5)-1/(8n + 6)].

The output is in base 16.

My code is the following:

```
function run(n) {
    return Math.pow(16, -n) * (4 / (8 * n + 1) - 2 / (8 * n + 4) - 1 / (8 * n + 5) - 1 / (8 * n + 6));
}

function convertFromBaseToBase(str, fromBase, toBase) {
    var num = parseInt(str, fromBase);
    return num.toString(toBase);
}


for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var a = run(i);
    console.log(convertFromBaseToBase(a, 16, 10));
}
```

So far, my output is the following:

```
1:3
2:0
3:0
4:0
5:1
6:7
7:3
8:1
9:7
10:3
```

Obviously, these are not the 10 first digits of PI.
My understanding is that values get rounded too often and that causes huge innacuracy in the final result.

However, I could be wrong, that's why I'm here to ask if I did anything wrong or if it's nodejs's fault. So I would loove if one of you guys have the answer to my problem!
Thanks!!

Comment: This is not correct formula for n-th digit of pi

Comment: How so ? It's the one I found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula

Comment: Which formula on that page? If you are referring to the first one, notice that it has sigma sign (for summation). It doesn't sum digits of pi to get number pi. In general: summing digits of some number will not get that number as a result.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, `4/(8n + 1) - 2/(8n + 4) - 1/(8n + 5) - 1/(8n + 6)` does not directly return the Nth hexadecimal digit of pi. I don't blame you, I made the same assumption at first. Although all the terms do indeed *sum* to pi, each individual term does *not* represent an individual hexadecimal digit. As seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula#BBP_digit-extraction_algorithm_for_.CF.80), the algorithm must be rewritten slightly in order to function correctly as a "digit spigot". Here is what your new `run` implementation ought to look like:

```
/**
   Bailey-Borwein-Plouffe digit-extraction algorithm for pi 
    <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula#BBP_digit-extraction_algorithm_for_.CF.80>
*/
function run(n) {
    var partial = function(d, c) {
        var sum = 0;

        // Left sum
        var k;
        for (k = 0; k <= d - 1; k++) {
            sum += (Math.pow(16, d - 1 - k) % (8 * k + c)) / (8 * k + c);
        }

        // Right sum. This converges fast...
        var prev = undefined;
        for(k = d; sum !== prev; k++) {
            prev = sum;
            sum += Math.pow(16, d - 1 - k) / (8 * k + c);
        }

        return sum;
    };

    /**
        JavaScript's modulus operator gives the wrong
        result for negative numbers. E.g. `-2.9 % 1`
        returns -0.9, the correct result is 0.1.
    */
    var mod1 = function(x) {
        return x < 0 ? 1 - (-x % 1) : x % 1;
    };

    var s = 0;
    s +=  4 * partial(n, 1);
    s += -2 * partial(n, 4);
    s += -1 * partial(n, 5);
    s += -1 * partial(n, 6);

    s = mod1(s);
    return Math.floor(s * 16);
}

// Pi in hex is 3.243f6a8885a308d313198a2e037073...
console.log(run(0) === 3); // 0th hexadecimal digit of pi is the leading 3
console.log(run(1) === 2);
console.log(run(2) === 4);
console.log(run(3) === 3);
console.log(run(4) === 15); // i.e. "F"
```

Additionally, your `convertFromBaseToBase` function is more complicated than it needs to be. You have written it to accept a string in a specific base, but it is already being passed a number (which has no specific base). All you should really need is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var a = run(i);
    console.log(a.toString(16));
}
```

Output:

```
3
2
4
3
f
6
a
8
8
8
```

I have tested this code for the first 30 hexadecimal digits of pi, but it might start to return inaccurate results once `Math.pow(16, d - 1 - k)` grows beyond `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, or maybe earlier for other reasons. At that point you may need to implement the modular exponentiation technique suggested in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: It's worth noting that this implementation does not include the standard optimization of using modular exponentiation instead of computing the power in its entirety as described in the linked article. If you really want the time complexity guarantees, you need that optimization.